# ElasticSearch paginate more than 10k records

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have to use ElasticSearch to store records and trying to create pagination using PIT (point in time). When I try to get records using sorting and pagination that have a sequence number greater than 10k, 50k etc., I have to query the records that come before the requested records.

**Example**:

Need to Request records with number 68000-69000.

**Steps of solving**:

1. Create PIT;
2. Make 6 dummy requests with size of batch 10k records using PIT;
3. Take last 10k records using PIT;
4. Take records Num.8000 - 9000 from step 3;
5. Close PIT.

The question is: Can I access the requested records without downloading the previous records (Skip 2-step in example above OR make it more lightweight)? Or should I change PIT (point in time) on another algorithm?

Comment: If you know the range, Why don't you use a range query?

Comment: @rabbitbr because i know abstract range but not range of ids or something like it